# how I can View VSCode and Android Emulator side by side on Mac full screen

Tags: android-studio, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

I did search about it but I couldn't  find away to View VSCode and Android Emulator side by side full screen on Mac
unless I use Android studio I can't put Android Emulator side by side with VSCode
it's only possible with iOS emulator